# Manual ACK with MQTT in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, mqtt

Is there a way with the Apache Camel MQTT module to manually acknowledge a message?

Use case: in a replicated service environment I want to be able to not acknowledge a message (and put it back on the broker) if a service is not able to handle that kind of message at that moment.

I see there is some functionality for this in the async PaHo client, but cannot find a configuration value for this in the mqtt module.

Comment: Are you talking about the camel-mqtt component? If so check its source code. But I would recommend using camel-paho as its more maintained

Comment: Yes, looked at the code, but that does not seem to do anything. Was wondering whether maybe it was hidden in Camel code somewhere since I assume this is something you want for many connectors.
Just did a test with random failing processing message and seems that message is then lost and not send to other clients.
Didn't know there was a Paho component. Will look at it. Thanks!